# Identify component emitting output property

Tags: angular

I have a generic modal logic on the root component to show a modal with a message passed using `@Output()` property by the child component. All the child components are passing value to the same `@Output()` property `OpenModal` as

```
<first (OpenModal)="OpenModal($event)"></first>
<second (OpenModal)="OpenModal($event)"></second>
```

I can get the modal display the appropriate message from any of the child component.

But the thing is, I want to pass a boolean back to the invoking component.

How can I determine which child component cause the change in the output property and in turn how can I pass the boolean to the child component once I close the dialog.

Stackblitz implementation of the concept at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xe3atu

PS: Is there a better way to implement a common modal component at the root. No extensions please.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the value as an object in event emitter as an object instead of a string as shown below,

```
@Output() OpenModal: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
@Input() response: string;

 OpenDialog(msg: string): void {
   this.OpenModal.emit({message:msg, parent: 'first'});
 }
```

Hence you can identify which component is emitting the event from app.component.ts

To get the boolean value from the modal component, currently you are creating the component inside container using factory via which you can get the value something like,

```
this.componentRef.instance.visible
```

But this will not have updated values on click of yes or no, hence to get the value from it when ever updated follow on of these ways,

i) Create the 'visible' variable as an subject and subscribe to it in the app component.

(or)

ii) Create the model component by using selector in app.component.ts rather using component factory. Show or hide the component conditionally based on the outputs from first/second component. In this way, we can get the value of boolean variable visible by directly emitting it as an output property from modal component.

Answer (score 0):

you can use input property to detect the change and get that change in to your child component but it required some boilerplate code here is the ex:

**HTML**

```html
<first (OpenModal)="OpenModal($event, 'first')" [sendData]="someData"></first>
<second (OpenModal)="OpenModal($event, 'second')" [sendData]="someData"></second>
```

**TS**

```
OpenModal(event, componentName) {
    this.someData = componentName
}
```

**first**

```
someData: string = null;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void { 
 if (changes.someData.currentValue != null && changes.someData.currentValue === 'first') 
  {
    console.log(changes.someData.currentValue); // here you can get the value from parent if and only if "someData" value is "first" 
  }
}
```